# Wifi Disabled in Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 dual boot

Tags: 16.04, wireless, windows-7

Dell Latitude E6530
Dual Boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 7

Computer worked fine yesterday. I was browsing on wifi in Ubuntu without issue.

Booted it up this morning and the wifi would not connect. Checked drop down menu in upper right.

[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9NHc.png)

Curiously the greyed out "Wi-Fi Disabled" does not respond to checked or unchecked "Enable Wi-Fi".

I connected ethernet,  updated Ubuntu, restarted the machine and nothing change.

Rebooted again with Windows 7. In Adapter Settings I can disable and enable the wifi card all day without change.

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You must have accidentally disabled the wireless by hardware switch/button.*

The hardware switch is usually a combination of `Fn+F10` or some other function keys. Look for the wireless radio/Wi-Fi/Airplane symbol on the keys of the first row on the keyboard (My latitude has it on PrntScrn key). They can be used to toggle the wireless.

If this doesn't work, check your BIOS to see if WLAN is disabled.

---

**UPDATE FROM COMMENT BELOW:**

Dell Latitude E6530 Wifi Hardware Switch is a slider on the right hand side of the keyboard just above the CD drive.

Comment: Dell Latitude E6530 Wifi Hardware Switch is a slider on the right hand side of the keyboard just above the CD drive.

Thanks, Yaksha!

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys ☺️ Fn + F5 worked for me on a Fujitsu lifebook. There is a little symbol on the F5 key that looks like an antenna with a couple of waves coming off it ((!)) Similar to my example here. Pressed it and all is good. Must have pressed it accidentally last night

Comment: Hello. OP made it clear it is a Dell computer.