# Airplane mode won' t turn off and wireless won' t turn on

Tags: wireless

My Wi-Fi appears to be disconnected because the airplane mode suddenly turned on but will not toggle to the off position. I went in a terminal and typed sudo rfkill unblock all after looking at the list but nothing happens.

Comment: Tried sudo rfkill disable all and got a list of commands and the statement: where Identifier is the index no. of an rfkill switch or one of : <Idx> all Wi-Fi wlan Bluetooth USB ultra wide band WiMAX wwan gPS FM nfc. What does that mean?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

Airplane mode must be turned on by hardware switch. Locate the wireless switch and toggle it.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/975455/574724 for more.